# Display Image- BLOB type- Oracle 11g Apex in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, oracle

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: One or more errors occurred during processing of command.
ORA-00936: missing expression

This is the error I get. Any suggestions?

My ashx handler code is:

```
     public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVER_NAME=XE)));User Id=sakthi_studdb;Password=sakthi;");
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select IMG_NAME, IMG_IMAGE from MYIMGTABLE where IMG_ID =:IMG_ID";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        OracleParameter ImageID = new OracleParameter(":IMG_ID",OracleDbType.Int32);
        ImageID.Value = context.Request.QueryString["IMG_ID"];
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageID);
        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dReader.Read();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dReader["IMG_IMAGE"]);
        dReader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My aspx code is:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="IMG_ID">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IMG_ID" HeaderText="IMG_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IMG_ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IMG_NAME" HeaderText="IMG_NAME" SortExpression="IMG_NAME" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IMG_IMAGE">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler1.ashx?IMG_ID=" + Eval("IMG_ID")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [IMG_ID],[IMG_NAME],[IMG_IMAGE] FROM [MYIMGTABLE]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[image]
This is the last puzzle for completing my project... Help!

Comment: I think you need to rename the parameter :IMG_ID to something that does not contain a colon, ex. P_IMG_ID.

Comment: The colon is fine; it's what specifies the following name as a parameter. Perhaps there's confusion over the data type? Try `ImageID.Value = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["IMG_ID"])` and see if that helps. Also note that once the query runs properly you may run into trouble reading the BLOB value. If you do, Google `ado.net oracle blob` for examples.

Comment: Do you need a space between = and your parameter value?

Comment: @EdGibbs No use :( It prompts the same error again. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @rontornambe I have attached the stack trace. Please see if its of any use..

Comment: Sakthi - sorry, that's all I had. If I were debugging this, I'd replace the `:IMG_ID` parameter in `cmd.CommandText = "Select IMG_NAME, IMG_IMAGE from MYIMGTABLE where IMG_ID =:IMG_ID"` with a constant value (an image ID that you know exists), then comment out the three lines where you set the parameter value, and then see what happens. If that works then there's a problem getting the parameter value from the page. I hope this helps.

Comment: A comment from this SO article suggests removing the colon from the parameter specification - OracleParameter ImageID = new OracleParameter("IMG_ID",OracleDbType.Int32); - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853927/display-image-blob-type-oracle-11g-apex-in-gridview-asp-net-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment22571972_15853927

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00936, ORA-936 is a generic error indicating a missing expression in the SQL statement that you have just executed.  Most probably this error is indicating that you have either missed a , [ comma ] or the from clause or where clause or some other part of the SQL that has just been parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're missing the setting of the BindByName property on the OracleCommand, defaults to false then it will bind by parameter position, I'm not sure if it may be the source of your problem, but try to set it and see what it does.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleCommandClass.htm#i997666
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featOraCommand.htm#i1007242